# groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.FileWriter.append()

Tags: java, groovy

Please help me to correct the error.

Output will be the file `invoicedetails.csv`, consists of all item details in csv format .

invoicedetails.csv

```
Computer,25000.0,2
Laptop,65000.0,1
Printer,8000.0,4
```

Error observed:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.io.FileWriter.append() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Double) values: [6.0]
>   Possible solutions: append(char), append(java.lang.CharSequence), append(java.lang.CharSequence, int, int), find(), any(), grep()

Program:

```
import java.io.FileWriter
class Main{

    static void main(String[] args)
    {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
        println "Enter the number of items:"
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())
        String[] item =new String[n]
        Double[] price =new Double[n]
        int[] quantity = new int[n]

        for(int i=0; i<n;i++)
        {
            int it = i+1
            println "Enter item $it details: "
            item[i] = br.readLine()
            price[i] = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine()).round(2)
            quantity[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine())
        }

        String COMMA_DELIMITER = ","
        String NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR = "\n"

        try
        {
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("invoicedetails.csv")

            for(int j=0; j<n;j++)
            {
                fileWriter.append(item[j])
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER)
                fileWriter.append(price[j])
                fileWriter.append(COMMA_DELIMITER)
                fileWriter.append(quantity[j])
                fileWriter.append(NEW_LINE_SEPARATOR)   
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            println e
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: I've improved formatting (especially code indenting) to make it easier unerstandable

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 blocks of code that will cause this exception in your code

```
Double[] price =new Double[n]
...
fileWriter.append(price[j])
```

and

```
int[] quantity = new int[n]
...
fileWriter.append(quantity[j])
```

`FileWriter#append` method accepts either `char` or `CharSequence` as parameter. To write these values you have to convert them to `CharSequence` (`String`).

E.g.

```
fileWriter.append(Double.toString(price[j]))

fileWriter.append(Integer.toString(quantity[j]))
```